# Google Maps se rompe en horizontal

Tags: javascript, google-maps

[image: La imagen]

Queria preguntar si a algo os ha pasado esto alguna vez? Es que en vertical me funciona bien y al ponerlo en horizontal se rompe

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad "Style" determina la apariencia del objeto "mapTypeControl". Esta propiedad reside en el objeto "google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle". Los diferentes valores aplicables son:

**• DEFAULT:**
El valor DEFAULT modifica la apariencia del "mapTypeControl" según el tamaño de la pantalla y otros factores. Si la pantalla es suficientemente grande, el control se mostrará en una barra horizontal, en caso contrario, se utilizará en forma de desplegable.

**• HORIZONTAL_BAR:**
Este valor mostrará siempre nuestro "mapTypeControl" en forma de barra horizontal, por muy pequeño que sea el tamaño de la pantalla.

**• DROPDOWN_MENU:**
Esta opción muestra siempre el control en forma de desplegable.

Aquí un ejemplo de código:
`mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR }`

Comment: Buenas Jorch, probando el mapa por defecto, sin estilos y sin tocar nada raro, cuando el mapa esta en vertical se ve todo bien, al poner lo en vertical se rompe